# Remover objeto de um ArrayList

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, arraylist

Eu tenho um arraylist de objetos, e preciso remover um objeto dele  da seguinte forma.

Eu preciso que esse objeto seja removido caso o atributo 'box' dele armazenar o mesmo valor que foi digitado no meu **`TextBox`**.

Por que eu estou montando um sistema de estacionamento, e quando o cliente faz o *checkout* e informa sua vaga, o objeto que tiver o valor do numero da vaga dele terá que ser excluído, eu tentei da seguinte forma.

```
foreach (cadastro cad in listVagas)
{
    if(cad.getBox() == Convert.ToInt32(consulta_box.Text))
    {
        listVagas.Remove(cadOBj);                    
    }
}
```

porém ele me da um erro quando eu clico no botão para fazer o checkout, no erro ele aponta para o foreach, o erro é o seguinte

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Coleção foi modificada; talvez a operação de enumeração não seja executada.

O erro acredito que seja por que eu tenha que informar o índice do objeto no vetor, e eu já procurei no Google porem não achei, como fazer para um objeto que tenha o valor de um atributo específico retornar seu índice.

Alguém teria alguma dica? Sabe alguma outra forma de conseguir remover este objeto? Ou como contornar este erro? Ou como descobrir o índice do objeto que armazene o valor especificado em determinado atributo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar acrescentando o [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (cadastro cad in listVagas.ToList())
        {
            if(cad.getBox() == Convert.ToInt32(consulta_box.Text))
            {
                listVagas.Remove(cadOBj);                    
            }
        }
```

**POR QUE FUNCIONA**

Simplesmente o `ToList` irá criar uma nova lista (em cache) e não sofrerá alterações subsequentes na coleção (a list original foi alterada).
Se por algum acaso, durante o `foreach`, for necessário tratar ocasionalmente um novo `add` ou mesmo o `remove`, a nova lista não reconhecerá essas alterações.

**DOCUMENTAÇÃO MSDN**

O método `ToList <TSource>` (`IEnumerable <TSource>`) força a avaliação de consulta imediata e retorna uma Lista `<T>` que contém os resultados da consulta. Você pode anexar este método à sua consulta para obter uma cópia em cache dos resultados da consulta.

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorre porque a coleção *listVagas* foi alterada durante o `foreach`. Crie uma coleção temporária e adicione nela os objetos que você deseja:

```
var listaTemp = new List<seuObjeto>();

foreach(var objeto in listaReal){
   if(!suaCondicao)
     listaTemp.add(objeto);
}
```

Outra solução é usar um `for`

```
for(var i = listaReal.Count - 1; i>=0 ;i--){
  if(suaCondicao)
    listaReal.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode utilizar uma expressão lambda

```
int idConsulta = Convert.ToInt32(consulta_box.Text);
listVagas = listVagas.Where(x=>x.getBox() != idConsulta).ToList();
```

Comment: Isso funciona com `ArrayList`?

Comment: Para fazer utilizando arrayList seria necessário primeiro converter o O ArrayList em um Array e depois em uma lista. Não seria muito performatico, eu não havia reparado que voce estava utilizando ArrayList. Como o bigown comentou na sua pergunta, seria interessante trabalhar direto com uma List, visto que o ArrayList está obsoleto...

Comment: A pergunta não é minha, só pra constar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar um `for` iterando da última posição para a primeira.

```
for(int i = listVagas.Count-1;i >=0; i--)
{
 if(listVagas[i].getBox() == Convert.ToInt32(consulta_box.Text))
    {
        listVagas.RemoveAt(i);                    
    }
}
```